# T-SQL with random returns multiple rows where one is expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, random

Consider the following T-SQL code (MS SQL Server 2014) that fetches a random row from a table variable:

```
DECLARE @priceClasses TABLE (
    RowIndex INT,
    PriceClassID NVARCHAR(MAX))
;

INSERT INTO @priceClasses VALUES
    (0, 'RETAIL')
    ,(1, 'WHOLESALE')
    ,(2, 'WHOLESALE2')
;

DECLARE @priceClassesCount AS INT;
SET @priceClassesCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @priceClasses);

SELECT 
    PriceClasses.RowIndex,
    PriceClasses.PriceClassID 
FROM
    @priceClasses AS PriceClasses
WHERE
    PriceClasses.RowIndex = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % @priceClassesCount;
```

The last `SELECT` statement, for some reason, sometimes returns 0 rows, sometimes 1, 2, or 3 rows.

It does not make sense to me. The value of the column is unique, and `ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % @priceClassesCount` cannot be multi-valued, can it?

The issue disappears when I declare `RowIndex INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY` instead of just `RowIndex INT`. Any thoughts?

Comment: You could also change this to get top 1 order by newid().

Comment: @SeanLange thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause is evaluated once per row.  That is the beauty of `NEWID()`.  Tragic beauty for your case.

If you are going to use this method, you might as well store the value in a variable:

```
DECLARE @priceClassesCount AS INT;
SET @priceClassesCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @priceClasses);
SET @RowIndex = 1 + (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % @priceClassesCount)

SELECT pc.RowIndex, pc.PriceClassID 
FROM @priceClasses pc
WHERE pc.RowIndex = @RowIndex;
```

Hopefully, `RowIndex` has no gaps in it.  That could be another reason why you are getting no rows.

Comment: It has no gaps indeed.

The problem is, I cannot store the value in a variable, because the reality is more complex (this whole thing is a subquery in a larger query, so I need to fetch a random row quite a few times).

Comment: @wh1t3cat1k . . . You should ask *another* question with more details about the problem you are really trying to solve.  Fetching multiple random rows is different from fetching one row.

Comment: I think I won't, knowing how NEWID() works, I can now deduce the correct solution myself. The missing bit was this feature of NEWID() that you have pointed out to. Thank you.

Comment: Modulo (`%`) can return a result of `0` and will never return `@priceClassesCount`. If `RowIndex` starts at `1` then this query might return zero rows now and then and will never return the "last" row.

Answer (score 4):

To get one random row, you can do this

```
SELECT TOP 1
    PriceClasses.RowIndex,
    PriceClasses.PriceClassID 
FROM
    @priceClasses AS PriceClasses
ORDER BY
    NEWID();
```

Although @GordonLinoff is correct, the requirement has a simpler solution